# Determine if IPv4 packet is fragmented

Tags: networking, ip, ipv4, ip-fragmentation

What is the right way to test if IP packet is a fragment?
Currently I only look at `MF` (More Fragments) bit in the IPv4 header. Is it sufficient?

Comment: I do not understand the TCP tag on the question. TCP has nothing to do with IPv4 packet fragmentation. TCP is completely unaware if IPv4 fragments a packet because the packet is reassembled before TCP receives it. Do not confuse TCP segmentation with IPv4 fragmentation because they are two completely separate and unrelated things.

Comment: @RonMaupin, thanks for correction, I fixed the tags.

Comment: @RonMaupin, if I deal with PCAP files (which means they may, and probably will, be IP-fragmented and TCP-fragmented, packets may be un-ordered, duplicated etc.), does it mean I should: a) reassemble IP fragments; and b) reassemble TCP segments ?

Comment: TCP does not fragment. TCP is a stream protocol that segments a stream, and that is a completely different thing than IPv4 fragmentation. IPv4 will get a TCP segment, and it will forward that, knowing nothing about TCP or its segmentation. If the MTU in the path shrinks, the IPv4 packet will get fragmented if it does not have the DF flag set. TCP knows nothing about that. The destination IPv4 will reassemble the packet fragment before sending that up to TCP, so TCP knows nothing about IPv4 fragmentation. IPv4 fragments and reassembles between the TCPs.

Comment: @RonMaupin, thanks for details! So I guess, my question was more about applications like e.g. DPI, or Intrusion Detection System and such, that can obtain packets in the middle (before they even hit TCP/IP) -- such applications have to be able to assemble IP fragments, and then, if required to analyze IP payload (TCP for example), should be able to reassemble segments.

Comment: I cannot explain exactly how application such as that do things (most IDSs are proprietary and will not disclose how things are done), but if you capture below layer-3, then you need to reassemble packet fragments to get the segments first, the reassemble segments. With IPv6, there is no path fragmentation, but there may be pre-fragmentation using fragment extension headers. Modern networking most uses PMTUD to prevent path fragmentation (a requirement for IPv6), and the TCP can use that to properly set the MSS to prevent pre-fragmentation altogether.

Comment: Most modern business routers and firewalls are now configured to drop packet fragments to prevent fragmentation attacks, so a business will almost never see fragmented packets in today's world.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is insufficient because the last packet fragment will not have the MF flag set. You must also look at the Fragment offset field, but that by itself is not sufficient because the first packet fragment will have that field set to 0.

If the Fragment Offset field > 0 then it is a packet fragment, or if the Fragment Offset field = 0 and the MF flag is set then it is a fragment packet.